# Clickhouse in Docker option experimental_allow_extended_storage_definition_syntax

Tags: docker, clickhouse

I'm trying to set the following option flag to 1: `experimental_allow_extended_storage_definition_syntax` to be able to test the new partitions features.

But I don't find where this can be set. Is it in a config file, while opening a session?

I'm using:

- Clickhouse in Docker under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Tabix in docker

If you have the exact command line to pass to be able to set that up with **Docker** that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is user settings, which could be set for a particular session or globally using `users.xml`.

Let's set the setting for default user (settings of all users are inherited from default user settings).
We will not modify `/etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml` directly, just add special file `experimental_allow_extended_storage_definition_syntax.xml` in `users.d` subdirrectory. It will be merged into main users config file.

So, Docker file commands:

```
RUN mkdir -p /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/
RUN chown -R clickhouse /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/
RUN echo '<yandex><profiles><default><experimental_allow_extended_storage_definition_syntax>1</experimental_allow_extended_storage_definition_syntax></default></profiles></yandex>' > /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/experimental_allow_extended_storage_definition_syntax.xml
```

You could see an example of the Dockerfile [here](https://gist.github.com/ludv1x/a891ea2a968bf371759e99227593967d#file-dockerfile)

Comment: Hi, Thank-you, I've tried to duplicate the dockerfile from the store, adding the proposed commend line in the file just before the "USER clickhouse" line. The image can be built and run, but that still does not activate the option.

Comment: Check that you use appropriate ClickHouse version (maybe you should rebuild the image with `--no-cache` option).
I added lines from my comment into Docker file, rebuild it, and it works with ClickHouse 1.1.54318:
https://gist.github.com/ludv1x/a891ea2a968bf371759e99227593967d#file-output-txt-L1

Comment: BTW We plan to enable this option by default in the next ClickHouse release. So, these tricks will be unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, it worked with the --no-cache option added to the docker build. thank-you.